# controller did not enter in function, already double checked database connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, development-environment

I created registration form in laravel, create controller for create new data & mentioned it on web.php but still it when i click on submit controller did not enter in function, already double checked database connection

web.php - Route::POST('/register', [customercontroller::class, 'Customer_Register'])->name('Customer_Register');

controller - public function Customer_Register(Request $request){

```
    $data = [

                'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                'mobile_name' => $request->mobile_name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
    ];
    echo "<pre>";       
    print_r($data);
    die;

    User::insert($data);
    return redirect('/login')->with('message','Data Added');
   


 }
```

I already checked several times name & database connection but the product table successfully getting data, but still not working

Comment: in your form page, what are the method you use?

Comment: why there is a `die()` in the function?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "controller did not enter in function"?

Answer (score -2):

Please share your view/blade file. We need to see it. You can edit your original post.

I had once same problem, I forgot 'method'.

I hope you have something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('Customer_Register')}}" >
    @csrf
    ...
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

If submit button is outside of the form, then:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('Customer_Register')}}" id="register-form">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
<button type="submit" form="register-form">Register</button>
```

*Note: you can also use dd($data); instead of this echo/print_r/die*, depends on your preference.

https://laraveldaily.com/post/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r

Comment: Please don't post an answer that does not resolve the initial problem. If you need more details, ask for them in the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase : Thanks, but no thanks. I tried to comment, but it says: You must have 50 reputation to comment. I dont have 50 reputation, so how should I ask the question? I can only post answer and comment my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: Feel free to post answers that **really** answer a given problem to gain reputation